# How to stop Java from automatically casting a char value to an int?

Tags: java, casting

the java compiler automatically casts a char value into a int, code like this will not raise an error:

```
public void foo(int i){
   // do something
}

char c = 'a';
foo(c);
```

Is there some way to stop the compiler from always casting chars to int or to throw an error?

Comment: `void foo(Integer i)` does not accept char values. Why would you want to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, compiler does widening conversion for primitive types mentioned https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2.

So, it automatically converts char to int.

You can avoid it by using Integer in foo. `void foo(Integer i)`

Answer (score 1):

What Java is doing is using ASCII code of that character you passed to your function.

so code below :

```
 char c = 'a';
    foo(c);

public void foo( int i){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

will have an output of : `97` which is 'a' char equivalent in int

> In addition, if the expression [on the right-hand side] is a constant expression of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the variable is of type byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>     expression is representable in the type of the variable.

what you must be aware of is that `int` is a primitive type in java but we can use wrapper classes instead like `Integer , Character , ...`.

so you can use :

```
public void foo( Integer i){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

that it will throw an exception :

```
 java: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wrapper `class` of `int` type as the method parameter like below,

```
public void foo(Integer i){
   // do something
}

char c = 'a';
foo(c);
```

This will show a compilation error.