# Can we pass a character as an index for integer array in java

Tags: java

I am new to java and practicing some programs.Can someone please explain me the following program at //line 10

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "xxyz";
        String str2 = "yxzx";
        System.out.println("Original strings: " + str1 + "  " + str2);
        System.out.println(stringPermutation(str1, str2));
    }

    public static void stringPermutation(String str1, String str2) {
        int[] arr = new int[500];
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
     System.out.println(arr[(int) str1.charAt(i)] += 1); //line 10

        } 
}
```

it's displaying the below output :

```
Original strings: xxyz  yxzx
1
2
1
1
```

Am trying to understand, how `arr[(int) str1.charAt(i)]i.e, arr['x']` is possible.
Please help me understanding this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685135/i-used-a-char-variable-as-array-index-to-a-boolean-array-in-java-how-does-the-c

Comment: Characters are basicly int values, for example `x==120`. You can check some ASCII table to see values of all the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialise an empty integer array the initial value for each of the item is zero, there for each index of `arr` will contain 0

```
int[] arr = new int[500];
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 0;
//...
arr[500] = 0;
```

The ASCII value for x is 120, y is 121 and z is 122, since the `arr` field contains 500 item then 120, 121 and 122 is in range.

In your loop you are adding 1 to each of the element. therefore in your `str1 = "xxyz"` when the first x is encounter 1 is added to index `arr[120]` so `arr[120]` becomes 1 and when x is encounter again 1 is added to the value which makes `arr[120]` becomes 2.

```
arr[(int) 'x'] += 1 //=> arr[120] + 1 = (0 + 1) = 1
arr[(int) 'x'] += 1 //=> arr[120] + 1 = (1 + 1) = 2
arr[(int) 'y'] += 1 //=> arr[121] + 1 = (0 + 1) = 1
arr[(int) 'z'] += 1 //=> arr[122] + 1 = (0 + 1) = 1
```

`arr['x']` is possible because in java **char** data type is a single 16-bit integer and **int** is 32-bit signed integer.

**Update:**

In the continuation for the program the second loop on `str2` is deducting one at the char index, if `str2` is a permutation of `str1` the value all the item in `arr` should reset to 0.

After the loop on str1. The values in the array are

```
arr[0] = 0
//...
arr[120] = 2 //arr['x']
arr[121] = 1 //arr['y']
arr[122] = 1 //arr['z']
//...
arr[500] = 0
```

When `str2 = "yxzx"`

```
arr[(int) 'y'] -= 1 //=> arr[121] - 1 = (1 - 1) = 0
arr[(int) 'x'] -= 1 //=> arr[120] - 1 = (2 - 1) = 1
arr[(int) 'z'] -= 1 //=> arr[122] - 1 = (1 - 1) = 0
arr[(int) 'x'] -= 1 //=> arr[120] - 1 = (1 + 1) = 0
```

After the loop on `str2` the values will be reset to 0

```
arr[0] = 0
//...
arr[120] = 0 //arr['x']
arr[121] = 0 //arr['y']
arr[122] = 0 //arr['z']
//...
arr[500] = 0
```

Hence looping through all the array if all the values are zeros then str2 is a permutation of str1.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: In Continuation to this program to 'Check if a given string is a permutation of another specified string' , am unable to understand the below logic                                                     `for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
   System.out.println(arr[(int) str2.charAt(i)] -= 1);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (arr[i] != 0)
    return false;
  }
  return true;
 }`

Comment: can you please explain me how   `for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { if (arr[i] != 0) return false; }` is used to check if string str2 is a perumtation of string str1.

Answer (score 1):

Because of ASCII value of x is 120, y is 121 and z is 122. 
So, Now

```
arr[x] => arr[120] = 1
arr[x] => arr[120] = 2
arr[y] => arr[121] = 1
arr[z] => arr[122] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you.Though some people downvoted it, i understood the concept now.

Comment: Thank you. Never thought that char will be converted to ASCII integer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. A `char` variable can hold any integer from 0 to 65,535. The value of a `char` literal is equal to an integer from the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] charArr = { '0', 'A', 'z' };
        int[] anArr = new int[123];

        // Initialize
        for (int i = 1; i < 123; i++) {
            anArr[i] = i * 10;
        }

        // Display
        for (char c : charArr) {
            System.out.print(anArr[c] + "\t");// Will display 480   650 1220
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
anArr['0'] = anArr[48] which has 48*10 stored in it
anArr['A'] = anArr[65] which has 65*10 stored in it
anArr['z'] = anArr[122] which has 122*10 stored in it
```